# Conditional Formatting based on sum of the 6 cells below

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I was Hoping to be fever along before i had to ask for help but.

using Google sheets i am trying to have a range of cells(a row specificity) change there background colour based on the Sum of the 6 cells directly below it in the

I know I am happy using the basic conditional forming and i have a formula witch will return true if the Sum = what i am looking for

```
=IF(SUM(D6:D11)=6,true,FALSE())
```

and this works if i copy and past it along but if i try to put it in the Custom formula is box i get told

> There was a problem while
>
> Cannot save the rule with invalid formula.
> so i take it that i am not using the box right

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Conditional formatting is ... conditional. There is not normally any need for IF(). Your formula should work as:

```
=Sum(D6:D11)=6
```

but over what range and what cells to format (other then D5) I can't help you, if required, without further details.

Please though do read the [google-spreadsheet] tag wiki.